# jQuery and SVG map. URL hash not updating correctly

Tags: jquery, svg, jsonp

I'm using an SVG map and jQuery to make a locator app where when someone clicks on a state it will bring up campuses within that state using jsonp. I'm adding a hash to the end of the path's url to tell jQuery which path was clicked.

It works except that the hash does not seem to be updating in time. You always see not where you clicked this time but where you clicked last time, always one click behind.

I tried to make a jsfiddle but it would not pull in the svg map so below is a demo.

Here is the demo (Click on "Search By State" tab): 
http://coypress.com/test/campus_locator_new.html

The jQuery in question:

```
// Map Clicks
    $("#tab2.tab_content").click(function() {

state = location.hash.replace("#","");

jsonLink = "http://ml.uscm.org/ministries.json?state=" + state + "&active=true&callback=?";
alert(jsonLink);
getResults();
});

function getResults() {
    stateTitle ="";
    var states = {"AL": "Alabama", "AK": "Alaska", "AZ": "Arizona", "AR": "Arkansas", "CA": "California", "CO": "Colorado", "CT": "Connecticut",
                  "DE": "Delaware", "FL": "Florida", "GA": "Georgia", "HI": "Hawaii", "ID": "Idaho", "IL": "Illinois", "IN": "Indiana", 
                  "IA": "Iowa", "KS": "Kansas", "KY": "Kentucky", "LA": "Louisiana", "ME": "Maine", "MD": "Maryland", "MA": "Massachusetts",
                  "MI": "Michigan", "MN": "Minnesota", "MS": "Mississippi", "MO": "Missouri", "MT": "Montana", "NE": "Nebraska", "NV": "Nevada", 
                  "NH": "New Hampshire", "NJ": "New Jersey", "NM": "New Mexico", "NY": "New York", "NC": "North Carolina", "ND": "North Dakota",
                  "OH": "Ohio", "OK": "Oklahoma", "OR": "Oregon", "PA": "Pennsylvania", "RI": "Rhode Island", "SC": "South Carolina", 
                  "SD": "South Dakota", "TN": "Tennessee", "TX": "Texas", "UT": "Utah", "VT": "Vermont", "VA": "Virginia", "WA": "Washington",
                  "WV": "West Virginia", "WI": "Wisconsin", "WY": "Wyoming", "DC": "Washington DC"};

    var stateTitle = states[state];

    $("#state").text("");
    $("#campus_title").text("Campuses in " + stateTitle);
    // alert("getResults Has Run!");
    $.getJSON(jsonLink,

    function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            $("#state").append(
                "<h5><a href='http://ml.uscm.org/ministries/" + value.id + ".json'>" + value.name +
                "</a> <small>(" + value.city +
                ", " + value.state +
                ")</small></h5>");
        });
    });
};
```

The related HTML:

```
<div id="tab2" class="tab_content"> 

   <p>Click on a state to see the campuses.</p>
   <div id="map"></div>
   <div class="campus-map-finder-results" style="padding-top: 50px;">
       <h2 id="campus_title"></h2>

<div id="state"></div>
   </div>
 </div><!-- #tab2 -->
```

Comment: You really should be using else if, waste of checks there. BUT you can avoid the 50 ifs, use an object! `var states = { "AL": "Alabama", ... }; var stateTitle = states[state];`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've updated the code on the demo.

Comment: Well you are probably going to have to add a small delay to allow for the change to take place. Other option is to listen for the [hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/hashchange) event [meaning you will have back/forward button support]

Comment: I thought delays only worked for the animation que? What would it look like to add one to this code?

Comment: I've found a jquery plugin that allows delays: http://www.theloveofcode.com/jquery/delayed/

Comment: delay...aka setTimeout()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@epascarello's comment above led me in the right direction. I needed to add a slight delay to allow the hash to get updated. I settled on using a small jquery plugin found at  http://theloveofcode.com/jquery/delayed